# How to conditional matching based on regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, leaflet

I have a map and want that every time I click on a feature property, it does some things. However, the condition is that the area I click has to match part of the name of the object properties of the JS variable.

Practically speaking, we have:

The function

```
ProcessiJSON.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
    if (e.target.feature.properties.NOME_COM.toUpperCase().match(/BONDENO/)) {

            $('.lead').html('ciaoooooo' + arrayItem.ANNO_DI_AVVIO);

}
}
```

The variable

```
    var ProcessiJSON =
[
    {
      "": 0,
      "ANNO_DI_AVVIO": 2010,
      "PROCESSI_BONDENO": "5",
      "PROCESSI_CAMPOSANTO": "",
      "PROCESSI_CAVEZZO": "",
      "PROCESSI_CENTO": "",
      "PROCESSI_CONCORDIA_SULLA_SECCHIA": "",
      "PROCESSI_CREVALCORE": "",
      "PROCESSI_FINALE_EMILIA": "",
      "PROCESSI_MEDOLLA": "",
      "PROCESSI_MIRABELLO": "",
      "PROCESSI_MIRANDOLA": "",
      "PROCESSI_NOVI_DI_MODENA": "",
      "PROCESSI_PIEVE_DI_CENTO": 1,
      "PROCESSI_REGGIOLO": "",
      "PROCESSI_SAN_FELICE_SUL_PANARO": ""} + many others
```

So, for example, if I click on area "BONDENO" I can get the number of "PROCESSI_BONDENO". Part of the name matches and part doesn't. I tried with str.match, but got no results so far. How could I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Your example is very unclear. 1: What is `e.target.feature.properties.NOME_COM` and 2. why do you only match it to `BONDENO` but show `ANNO_DI_AVVIO` ???

Comment: `.match(/\w*?BONDENO\w*/g)` should work.

Comment: 1)the name of the area, in this case `BONDENO`; 2) `ANNO_DI_AVVIO` is another thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
const ProcessiJSON = [
    {
      "": 0,
      "ANNO_DI_AVVIO": 2010,
      "PROCESSI_BONDENO": "5",
      "PROCESSI_CAMPOSANTO": "",
      "PROCESSI_CAVEZZO": "",
      "PROCESSI_CENTO": "",
      "PROCESSI_CONCORDIA_SULLA_SECCHIA": "",
      "PROCESSI_CREVALCORE": "",
      "PROCESSI_FINALE_EMILIA": "",
      "PROCESSI_MEDOLLA": "",
      "PROCESSI_MIRABELLO": "",
      "PROCESSI_MIRANDOLA": "",
      "PROCESSI_NOVI_DI_MODENA": "",
      "PROCESSI_PIEVE_DI_CENTO": 1,
      "PROCESSI_REGGIOLO": "",
      "PROCESSI_SAN_FELICE_SUL_PANARO": "" 
}]

const findValues = (key) => {
  key = key.toUpperCase();
  return Object.keys(ProcessiJSON[0]).filter(item => item.indexOf(key) !=-1)
}  

let clicked = "Bondeno";
let match = findValues(clicked)
match.forEach(key => $(".lead").append('ciao fatto '+key+':',ProcessiJSON[0][key]+"<br/>") )

clicked = "Mira";
match = findValues(clicked)
match.forEach(key => $(".lead").append('ciao fatto '+key+':',ProcessiJSON[0][key]+"<br/>") )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lead"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But can I mix JQuery with it? Like this: `match.forEach(key => $('.lead').html('ciao fatto' + ProcessiJSON[0][key] )`, because it doesn't work when I put it in my code